# Replace the first character of each line

Tags: vim, vi

In vi, how to replace the first character in each line if it is the specified character `a` with another character `!`? If the first character is space，do not do anything.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Global substitute the first character of a line if it is 'a':

```
:%s/^[a]/!/
```

Global substitute the first character of a line if it is not space:

```
:%s/^[^ ]/!/
```

Comment: The brackets are not necessary in the first example

Comment: Yes, I just like them there but they are totally useless

Comment: You can also use `\S` for non-whitespace character.

Comment: Though this is very late, I used this answer to add a string `abc` at the beginning of each lines of a file:

`:%s/^/abc/`

Answer (score 5):

Or using global command `:g`

`:g/^a/s//!`

this will automatically skip all lines that begin with a space or a character that does not match `^a` and replace all matching with `!`